# Pattern-match list of tuple Strings

Tags: list, haskell

So I have a lost of String tuples in Haskell.
I declared a type for that:

```
type Book = [(String, String)]
```

Then I declared an empty book:

```
emptyBook :: Book
emptyBook = []
```

And now I want to create a function that inserts elements to a book. My solution:

```
insert :: String -> String -> Book -> Book
insert a b emptyBook = (a,b) : []
insert a b (x : xs)= (a, b) : (x:xs)
```

But the function insert is not working. The compiler loads the module but gives the warning 'Pattern match is redundant'.

Executing insert `"a" "1" [("b","2")]` gives `[("a","1")]`
instead of `[("a","1"),("b","2")]`

Do you know whats going wrong here?

Comment: It's *tuple(s)*, not *tupel(s)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clause

```
insert a b emptyBook = (a,b) : []
```

defines `insert` as a function of three general arguments `a`, `b` and `emptyBook`. Well, the last isn't actually used, but that makes no difference – that clause will succeed, no matter what arguments you pass in.

The third argument also *shadows* the top-level definition `emptyBook` – basically this makes it so that within the scope of the function, `emptyBook` is now whatever book you pass in, no matter whether it's empty.

GHC can actually give a warning highlighting this real problem with your code, if you tell it to give generous warnings:

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:~$ runhaskell -Wall /tmp/wtmpf-file2776.hs 

/tmp/wtmpf-file2776.hs:7:12: Warning:
    This binding for ‘emptyBook’ shadows the existing binding
      defined at /tmp/wtmpf-file2776.hs:4:1

/tmp/wtmpf-file2776.hs:7:12: Warning:
    Defined but not used: ‘emptyBook’
```

If you want `emptyBook` to be a *constant* that should be matched on, you have to make it explicit that this is not a newly-bound argument variable. A couple of options:

- (***Not*** recommended) use equality comparison instead of pattern matching

  ```
  insert a b book
    | book==emptyBook  = (a,b) : []
  insert a b (x : xs)  = (a, b) : (x:xs)
  ```

  We generally avoid equality comparison in Haskell – it's less general, less efficient and more error-prone than pattern matching.
- (*Very **not*** recommended) use a C-preprocessor macro (Template Haskell would also work) to actually insert literally `[]` in that pattern matching. You can't have a variable named `[]`, so this will do the right thing:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

  #define emptyBook []

  insert :: String -> String -> Book -> Book
  insert a b emptyBook = (a,b) : []
  insert a b (x : xs) = (a, b) : (x:xs)
  ```

  Such macro definitions don't work very well with Haskell – they're completely oblivious of the languages scopes, can't be exported etc..
- (*Not **very*** recommended) use *pattern synonyms*. Those are essentially the modern, Haskell-native way of achieving the behaviour I did above with a CPP macro:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

  pattern EmptyBook :: Book
  pattern EmptyBook = []

  insert :: String -> String -> Book -> Book
  insert a b emptyBook = (a,b) : []
  insert a b (x : xs) = (a, b) : (x:xs)
  ```

So, what *would* be the recommended solution? Well, as Willem Van Onsem says, you just don't need that clause at all – it's already a special case of the second clause!

```
insert :: String -> String -> Book -> Book
insert a b (x : xs) = (a, b) : (x:xs)
```

...which is the same as

```
insert a b (x : xs) = (a, b) : x : xs
```

or

```
insert a b xxs = (a, b) : xxs
```

or

```
insert a b = ((a, b) :)
```

or

```
import Data.Function.Pointless

insert=(:).:(,)
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't get why you:

1. use `emptybook` in your pattern matching part, instead of `[]`;
2. why you repeat `(x:xs)` both in the left and in the right part of the expression;
3. make a distinction between an empty book and a non-empty book.

## Why it doesn't work

Because Haskell, like many other languages uses *variable scopes*, and Haskell sees `emptybook` in your function **as a variable**. It does not see (at least not there) that `emptybook` is a function somewhere defined. So could have written:

```
insert a b c = (a,b) : []
```

as well (as second line in your function definition). Now since you define a variable `c` and did not put any constraints (guards, patterns,...) on it, it **matches with everything**: so a non-empty book as well. Therefore Haskell will always take the first line. In fact the compiler already warns you for this. It says:

```
haskell.hs:9:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for ‘insert’: insert a b (x : xs) = ...
```

This means that the last line of your function definition overlaps with the previous lines. In that case you have probably done something wrong.

## Alternative

You can simply use:

```
insert :: String -> String -> book -> book
insert a b xs = (a,b) : xs
```

or even shorter:

```
insert :: String -> String -> book -> book
insert a b = (:) (a,b)
```

Furthermore types are usually denoted with a *capital letter*, so you better use `Book` instead of `book`.

Comment: While this is a really good list of improvements to the current code, it doesn't actually answer the question.